# I get NPX: command not found whenever I run create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Whenever I try to create a react app, the CMD always outputs the error below NPX: command not found. I looked at previous GitHub and Stack Overflow questions that were same as mine, however removing and then adding NPX again doesn't work. I also uninstalled node.js and then reinstalled it but that didn't work either! Below is the error and my node version:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oZ95.png)

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm i npm` to install node package manager if it was not included in your installation. To make sure the installation was a success run `npm -v` in the command line.